# how do i get deployment name from helm status to write in bash script?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can i get the deployment name from the helm status output.As you can see i can get resources but could not be  able to parse the deployment name.Is there anyway to get the deployment name.Deployment name is need for using in bash script.

```
helm status release_name -o json | jq '.info.status.code'
helm status release_name -o json |jq '.info.status.resources'
```

Helm version : 2.x

Comment: you need to inspect the `jq .manifest`

Comment: There is no  field name manifest in helm status output.
if you are meaning "helm get manifest release_name --output json" which results 
Error: unknown flag: --output

Comment: I assume you are on Helm 2.x version

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention, yes i am in helm 2.x version

Comment: `helm get manifest` will print out the Kubernetes YAML that's being deployed, but it's not necessarily easy to extract the Deployment name(s) as distinct from other Kubernetes resources.  Extracting it using a Python script with a native YAML parsing library might be more straightforward.

Comment: yes @DavidMaze,it will be easier to extract it using python.But i want it to be bash cause i need it to run in jenkins.

Comment: You can [`readJSON`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) or [`readYaml`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) in your Jenkins pipeline code too.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze , i thinks this is a good approach but as i can get values from "helm get values -a release_name  --output json ", i will write  deployment name in values.